# How to approximate error on Chi-Squared Fit when bin counts are zero

Tags: chi-squared-test, least-squares, fitting, curve-fitting

I am using a galaxy image simulator that provides a 2D histogram that has the number of photons per pixel (bin) $N$. I am currently using a least-squares residual:

$\sum_{bin}(f_{data}-f_{model})^2$

for the fitter (The Levenberg-Marquardt Algorithm) to approximate certain parameters of this "image". This least-squares fit does not divide by the uncertainty in each bin.

Now when I decided to approximate the uncertainty in each bin by $\sqrt{N}$ such as:

$\sum_{bin}\frac{(f_{data}-f_{model})^2}{\sqrt{N}}$

then I have to divide by zero in bins that contain zero entries. The way I remedy this is that I make the error equal to 1.

Using this form, I receive negative biases for a subset of my parameters. How can I remedy this?

And, as a comment pointed out, the second equation is not a chi-squared value?

Comment: This does not appear to be a chi-squared statistic. The correct statistic uses the *model* value to estimate a *variance* in the denominator. Wouldn't it be more constructive to explain what you are trying to accomplish instead of asking us to fix a procedure that looks so completely broken to begin with?

Comment: Do you have $f_{data}$ when $N = 0$?  If not, can't you just skip dividing 0 by 0 and call it a day?